# pandas/python: drop duplicates of same strings with different order

Tags: python, pandas

is it possible to drop duplicate of rows with the same strings but of different order within the same column?

exampe: dl3_hr_rank.r0 and hr_dl3_rank.r0

code for df before drop:

```
data = {'item':['dl3_hr_rank.r0','hr_dl3_rank.r0','hr_kl3_rank.r0',
                'kl3_hr_rank.r0','hcrfr_hr_rank.r0',
                'hr_hcrfr_rank.r0','hcfr_hkfr_rank.r0_wp','hkfr_hcfr_rank.r0_wp',
                'hr_krl2_rank.r0_wp','krl2_hr_rank.r0_wp',],
'result':[1.17,1.17,1.17,1.17,1.13,1.13,1,1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

code for df after drop:

```
data = {'item':['dl3_hr_rank.r0','hr_kl3_rank.r0',
                'hcrfr_hr_rank.r0',
                'hcfr_hkfr_rank.r0_wp',
                'hr_krl2_rank.r0_wp'],
'result':[1.17,1.17,1.13,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

ps.i'm having trouble inserting tables with the  command..
many thanks, regards

Comment: Can you please check whether `df[~df['item'].apply(sorted).duplicated()]` gives you the correct result? It is different from the output dataframe you provided.

Comment: @  timgeb, thanks for the response, however, i'm getting an error: SystemError: <built-in function duplicated_object> returned a result with an error set

Comment: why "hjfr_hcfr_rank.r0_wp" not in the result df? it isn't a duplicate

Comment: @Niv Dudovitch sorry, it was a typo, i;ve corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df[~df.item.str.split('_').apply(frozenset).duplicated(keep='first')]
```

Result df:
[image]

- Use pandas.Series.str.split to split by '_'
- Use apply(frozenset) to get a hashable set such that I can use duplicated
- Use pandas.Series.duplicated with keep='first' to keep only the first occurrence of duplicate strings